# Moving optional_permission to required permission in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I currently have `notifications` added as an `optional_permission` for my Chrome extension.

If I change that to a required `permission`, what will happen to the users that have already accepted notifications? Will they still have the extension disabled for them? Will it be a seamless transition?

Related Links: [extension permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/permissions/), [extension permission warnings](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/permission_warnings/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the [source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/extensions/extension_service.cc;l=1516;drc=a0b80cf17496b8d5bb885a0c17f1d73d583fd498) there won't be a warning for users that have already accepted notifications because the update routine accounts for these runtime-granted permissions explicitly.

But if you add several permissions of which some aren't yet granted, the extension will be disabled.